# the proof of the supremum of the continuity function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, supremum-and-infimum

I totally have no idea about doing this question.Could someone help me?I'd appreciate it!

Assume $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ for some real numbers $a < b$ and that $f(a) < y < f(b)$.

Deﬁne the set $S := \{z \in [a, b] | \forall x \in [a, z], f(x) < y\}$.

Let $c = \sup S$. Prove $c < b$.

Comment: What do you know about $c$ if the inequality $c<b$ is violated?

Comment: Sorry,I have no idea about that.

Comment: If my answer helped you, you should give it an upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We only have to show that $c\neq b$. For this, we prove that $f(c) < f(b)$. First of all, let $\varepsilon := f(b)-y$. As $f$ is continuous at $c$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|x-c|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(c)|<\varepsilon$. As $c = \sup S$, there exists $z\in S$ such that $|z-c| < \delta$. Hence, $|f(z)-f(c)| < \varepsilon$ and therefore
$$
f(c) < f(z) + \varepsilon < y + \varepsilon = f(b).
$$

Comment: Thanks for your help, but when I give you an upvote,it shows that:Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I don't think you can. This seems to be a flaw in the scoring. I think accepting an answer should automatically upvote irrespective of reputation.

Comment: Now you can. ;o)

Comment: yes , I have upvoted

Comment: but I am confused that why you can say  f is continuous at c

Comment: Because $c$ is definitely contained in $[a,b]$ and you wrote that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 1):

Directly from the definition of continuity. There is $\delta>0$ such that for $x\in (b-\delta,b)$ $f(x)>y$. Hence $\sup(S)\leq b-\delta<b$.

In fact you only need continuity at $b$.

Comment: The point is that $f$ is continuous at $c$, not at $b$.

Comment: But $f$ is continuous at $c$ is not necessary. So long as $f$ is continuous at $b$ the result follows. Notice I didn't use continuity at $c$.

Comment: Ok. However, I do not really like your answer because you shift the problem more or less from $b$ to $b-\delta$. The point is: Why is $\sup S\le b-\delta$?

Comment: Because there's an interval around $b$ which can't contain any members of $S$. Quoting continuity at $c$ is just unnecessarily complicating things.

Comment: Well... You won! ;o)